# Angular 6 - Form.valueChanges doesn't update form.touched property (Template driven Form)

Tags: rxjs, angular6

```
  trackFormChanges() {

    this.form.valueChanges.pipe(
      debounceTime(300),
      distinctUntilChanged())
      .subscribe(data => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (this.form.dirty && this.form.touched) {   //dirty works but touched property has old value  
          this.prompt = true;
        }
        if (this.recordCopy) {
          if (_.isEqual(this.record, this.recordCopy)) {
            this.isSaved = true;
          } else {
            this.successes = [];
            this.isSaved = false;
          }
        }
      }, 500);
    });
  }
```

I am trying to check if the form is touched when the valueChanges is triggered, `form.dirty` works but `form.touched` are false and doesn't update I don't want to subscribe to `form.statuschanges`, and more overvalue changes trigger multiple times. Is there a way we can handle this?

Answer (score 0):

That's the implementation of the FormGroup, it doesn't touch parent FormGroups if you touch a control - only the control will be touched.

Even more `form.statuschanges` doesn't react on touch too, it emits only when related FormGroup / FormControl becomes valid / invalid.

In your case you need reconsider usage of `form.touched` avoiding it or adding a extralogic to touch parent FromGroups, but child controls don't have pointers to their parents.